# Missing translations in a collection on initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, translation, rails-i18n

I am trying to add I18n on a collection in one of my models. When I initialize the server/console and I called the collection, the translation is missing, but after reloading the app or the console, the translations appear.

Here is the example:

```
[1] pry(main)> Listing::CONDITIONS
=> [["translation missing: en.activerecord.attributes.listing.conditions.new", 
"new"], ["translation missing: en.activerecord.attributes.listing.conditions.used-new", 
"used-new"], ["translation missing: en.activerecord.attributes.listing.conditions.used-vgood", 
"used-vgood"], ["translation missing: en.activerecord.attributes.listing.conditions.used-good", 
"used-good"], ["translation missing: en.activerecord.attributes.listing.conditions.used-acceptable", 
"used-acceptable"]]
[2] pry(main)> reload!
Reloading...
=> true
[3] pry(main)> Listing::CONDITIONS
=> [["New", "new"],
["Used - Like New", "used-new"],
["Used - Very Good", "used-vgood"],
["Used - Good", "used-good"],
["Used - Acceptable", "used-acceptable"]]
```

Any ideas?